# Reading files in a particular order in python

Tags: python, file, order-of-execution

Lets say I have three files in a folder: file9.txt, file10.txt and file11.txt and i want to read them in this particular order. Can anyone help me with this?

Right now I am using the code

```
import glob, os
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join( '*.txt')):
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + infile
```

and it reads first file10.txt then file11.txt and then file9.txt.

Can someone help me how to get the right order?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Files on the filesystem are not sorted. You can sort the resulting filenames yourself using the [`sorted()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + infile
```

Note that the `os.path.join` call in your code is a no-op; with only one argument it doesn't do anything but return that argument unaltered.

Note that your files will sort in alphabetical ordering, which puts `10` before `9`. You can use a custom key function to improve the sorting:

```
import re
numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
def numericalSort(value):
    parts = numbers.split(value)
    parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
    return parts

 for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'), key=numericalSort):
    print "Current File Being Processed is: " + infile
```

The `numericalSort` function splits out any digits in a filename, turns it into an actual number, and returns the result for sorting:

```
>>> files = ['file9.txt', 'file10.txt', 'file11.txt', '32foo9.txt', '32foo10.txt']
>>> sorted(files)
['32foo10.txt', '32foo9.txt', 'file10.txt', 'file11.txt', 'file9.txt']
>>> sorted(files, key=numericalSort)
['32foo9.txt', '32foo10.txt', 'file9.txt', 'file10.txt', 'file11.txt']
```

Comment: HI. The sorted function does not change the order unfortunately.

Comment: @user1620012: Updated my answer to improve the sorting order.

Comment: hi..actually my files have the names like.. text-text9-text.txt, text-text10-text.txt etc.

Comment: @user1620012: my sorting function will work just fine with those.

Comment: @user1620012: Great. :-) Don't forget to mark the answer that helped you the most as accepted (click on the green 'V' mark under the vote score).

Comment: But for some reason I caanot do the remaining part of that task anymore, which basically involves some complicated mathematical manipulations. :(

Comment: @user1620012: If you have a new problem, post a new question. :-)

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters Extremely helpful

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that this still works as of Python 3.7.4!  I did swap out glob.glob with os.listdir(FILEPATH) but everything else I left the same.  Thank you so much for the code!

Answer (score 12):

You can wrap your `glob.glob( ... )` expression inside a `sorted( ... )` statement and sort the resulting list of files. Example:

```
for infile in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
```

You can give `sorted` a comparison function or, better, use the `key= ...` argument to give it a custom key that is used for sorting.

Example:

There are the following files:

```
x/blub01.txt
x/blub02.txt
x/blub10.txt
x/blub03.txt
y/blub05.txt
```

The following code will produce the following output:

```
for filename in sorted(glob.glob('[xy]/*.txt')):
        print filename
# x/blub01.txt
# x/blub02.txt
# x/blub03.txt
# x/blub10.txt
# y/blub05.txt
```

Now with key function:

```
def key_func(x):
        return os.path.split(x)[-1]
for filename in sorted(glob.glob('[xy]/*.txt'), key=key_func):
        print filename
# x/blub01.txt
# x/blub02.txt
# x/blub03.txt
# y/blub05.txt
# x/blub10.txt
```

**EDIT:**
Possibly this key function can sort your files:

```
pat=re.compile("(\d+)\D*$")
...
def key_func(x):
        mat=pat.search(os.path.split(x)[-1]) # match last group of digits
        if mat is None:
            return x
        return "{:>10}".format(mat.group(1)) # right align to 10 digits.
```

It sure can be improved, but I think you get the point. Paths without numbers will be left alone, paths with numbers will be converted to a string that is 10 digits wide and contains the number.

Comment: The sorted function does not change the order unfortunately.

Comment: It does -- `y/blub05.txt` moves from last position one up because `blub05.txt` comes before `blub10.txt`. Only the file name is compared without the directory in `key_func`.

Comment: Actually my files dont have the zeros. They are renamed as x/blub1.txt
x/blub2.txt
x/blub10.txt and this produces a wrong order, even with the sort command.
x/blub3.txt
y/blub5.txt

Comment: When sorting strings '1' comes before '9', which is why you are seeing this behavior. You can change key_func to isolate that number per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the sort from 'ASCIIBetical' to numeric by isolating the number in the filename. You can do that like so:

```
import re

def keyFunc(afilename):
    nondigits = re.compile("\D")
    return int(nondigits.sub("", afilename))

filenames = ["file10.txt", "file11.txt", "file9.txt"]

for x in sorted(filenames, key=keyFunc):
   print xcode here
```

Where you can set filenames with the result of glob.glob("*.txt");

Additinally the keyFunc function assumes the filename will have a number in it, and that the number is only in the filename. You can change that function to be as complex as you need to isolate the number you need to sort on.

Comment: What if there are files with different names, grouped with numbers? Ex. `foo1.txt`, `foo2.txt` .. `foo10.txt`, then `bar1.txt`, `bar2.txt`, etc? Or there are two sets of numbers in the filename?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That wasn't a requirement of the original question, and I think you know the answer. :)

Comment: Well, most likely the question used a small sample of files; as it turns out the `9`, `10`, `11` sequence was the crucial part. We cannot assume we have the whole picture here. :-)

Comment: Agreed on the big picture part. I assume the person asking the question can translate from a specific answer to a more general answer if so needed. Hence I try to give a minimal but complete answer (based on their question), and hope they can succeed from there.

Comment: Generally speaking, I agree, but with regular expressions that doesn't always work out :-)

Comment: Well regex is a topic worthy of an entire book. I certainly don't expect anyone to explain that in one SO question. :) But I do see your point.

Comment: If it is possible to give files names like file09.txt, file10.txt, file11.txt, the sorting should work without the need to specify custom parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
glob.glob(os.path.join( '*.txt'))
```

returns a list of strings, so you can easily sort the list using pythons [sorted() function](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).

```
sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join( '*.txt')))
```

Comment: sorted function gives the same result  Current File Being Processed is: file10.txt.txt
Current File Being Processed is: file11.txt.txt
Current File Being Processed is: file9.txt.txt

Answer (score -5):

```
for fname in ['file9.txt','file10.txt','file11.txt']:
   with open(fname) as f: # default open mode is for reading
      for line in f:
         # do something with line
```

Comment: Actually I have a few hundrdes of files which I want to process.So making the list is quite inconvenient.