# How do I read all text files in a folder into an array in original order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number of 1500 .txt files in a folder and each file has only one line like this:

```
24.171683 25.663069 26.996733 27.684257 28.411782 29.253564
```

The name of files is the combination of numbers and letters such as Animation1000_1_0.txt, Animation1000_10_1.txt, ... Now I need to read all .txt files' content in an array, but based on their order in the original folder. For this I used the following code:

```
psnr_bitrate=np.vstack([np.loadtxt(path, dtype='float') for path in glob.iglob(r'E:/PSNR_RDCURVE/*.txt')])
```

but when I checked the `psnr_bitrate` array, it does not have the same order as files and I do not know how this code read the files. Do you know what should I read the files in an array with same order as files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried *sorted* statement, like described here?
[Reading files in a particular order in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093940/reading-files-in-a-particular-order-in-python)

```
for path in sorted(glob.iglob(r'E:/PSNR_RDCURVE/*.txt'))
```

Comment: This will not result in a numerical order. It will be [lexicographic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950646/what-is-lexicographical-order) instead, file_10 will be listed before file_2. The link you quote has a very good answer how to produce numerical order.